# Add a content-script to a window.print() dialog

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Who knows how to add a content-script to window.print() a dialog.
My extension must run one window.print() then choose a needed printer and press print.
then we run one more window.print() and choose other printer and set up needed setting pressing the print button.

So I couldn't reach the window that runs by window.print()
Who know how to put there your own code???

Comment: It's impossible because the dialog is a built-in page.

Comment: I want to manage built-in pages... Does it seem to be there the way of doing it?

Comment: No, the built-in pages aren't manageable.